# results.pandas().xyxy[0] in only outputting data for one image rather than four

Tags: yolov5

I am trying to get the output stored in a variable so that it can be used later on for more processing.

But to get to that stage I am facing a challenge with this code

```
######INFERENCE ON P6 MODELS*****************************************************************************
import torch
import glob
from natsort import natsorted
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import os

model = torch.hub.load('/Users/yolov5', 'custom', path='/User/yolov5/runs/train/exp11/weights/best.pt', source='local', force_reload=True)  # custom trained model
model.conf = 0.25  # NMS confidence threshold

Path = 'User/yolov5/data/images/'

imgs = [cv2.imread(file) for file in natsorted(glob.glob(Path+"/*.jpg"))]


# Inference
results = model(imgs,size=640)

# Results:

#results.save() # or .print() .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
results.pandas()
#print(results.print())
#print(results.pandas().xyxy[:])
# results.show()
#results.pandas().xyxy[0]


#print(results)
#print(results.pandas().xyxy[0])
# dfm = pd.DataFrame(results.pandas().xyxy[0])#, columns = ['Loss','Accuracy']
# # #dfm['Classes'] = classes.tolist()
# predict_labs = 'pred_yolo_individual.csv'
# with open(predict_labs, mode='w') as fd:
#      dfm.to_csv(fd)

#results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
#results.render()
results.xyxy[0]  # im predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0] 
results.print()
# pred = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
# for index, row in pred.iterrows():
#     print(row['class'], row['confidence'], row['name'])
```

As you can see I am trying loads of stuff to get this going but some major details I am missing that is not getting the right output as desired.

I would like to get the output like this format below for the folder of images that I have.

```
# Results
results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.

results.xyxy[0]  # im predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # im predictions (pandas)
#      xmin    ymin    xmax   ymax  confidence  class    name
# 0  749.50   43.50  1148.0  704.5    0.874023      0  person
# 2  114.75  195.75  1095.0  708.0    0.624512      0  person
# 3  986.00  304.00  1028.0  420.0    0.286865     27     tie
```

*** THE ISSUE IS***
When I use the same code I am only getting one output!!!!!?!?!?!
If I do a

```
print(results.pandas().xyxy[0:])
```

I am seeing the output as demonstrated below but not in the structured format as above:

```
YOLOv5  v7.0-72-g064365d Python-3.10.6 torch-1.13.1 CPU

Fusing layers... 
Model summary: 212 layers, 20856975 parameters, 0 gradients, 47.9 GFLOPs
Adding AutoShape... 
[         xmin       ymin        xmax        ymax  confidence  class      name
0  539.859314  119.92907  602.884216  245.533752    0.353711      1  Stabbing, Empty DataFrame
Columns: [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence, class, name]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence, class, name]
Index: [],          xmin       ymin         xmax        ymax  confidence  class      name
0  709.833496  66.843300  1025.770752  800.782593    0.771696      1  Stabbing
1   84.628845   4.153772   461.863617  833.189636    0.632551      1  Stabbing]
```

Please assist, and thank you in advance for acknowledging my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following code to get the desired output:

```
# Inference
results = model(imgs, size=640)

# Results:

preds = results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # im predictions (pandas)
# print(preds)

# Create dataframe and write to file
dfm = pd.DataFrame(preds)
dfm.columns = ['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax', 'confidence', 'class', 'name']
predict_labs = 'pred_yolo_individual.csv'
dfm.to_csv(predict_labs, index=False)
```

This will create a CSV file containing all the predictions in the desired format.